# Why increasing number of cameras on drone improves resolution?

Tags: technique, pixel-density, pixel-size

`Pegasus drone` and in general use normal cameras but surprisingly have the same effect of high magnification telescope.

I know using several monitors improves display pixels count which is reasonable, but somehow the similar technique works for drones.

Comment: "Pegasus drone" is an overloaded term. At the minimum, it could refer to an inexpensive $80 toy, a site security drone platform, or to a several million dollar unmanned combat air vehicle. Please provide to the "Pegasus drone" you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the drone in question, but it sounds like a (somewhat) common practice in astronomy: [aperture synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_synthesis). The basic idea is that having multiple cameras spread out can effectively work like a bigger single camera. Sort of.

You can find a paper from 2004 that discusses doing just this at https://graphics.stanford.edu/~wilburn/wilburn_thesis.pdf